# When i click an item in my collection view i got this error

Tags: ios, nsarray, plist, nsdictionary

I have a collectionview but when i tried to click the image the it showing this error ? The whole application is a tabbar application ,so all other tabs are working . except the last tab images.
iam taking images from plist for displaying it into collectionview
this is error

```
        *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI 
    objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'*** First throw call stack: (0x1e92012 


    0x1969e7e 0x1e47b44 0x58b91 0x56686 0x137cf 0x98f1c7 0x98f232 0x98f4da 0x9a68e5 0x9a69cb 0x9a6c76 


`0x9a6d71 0x9a789b 0x9a7e93 0x9a7a88 0xd03e63 0xcf5b99 0xcf5c14 0xdaf5d9 0xdc1182 0xdc1394 0x197d705

 0x9bb93c 0x9bb9ac 0x197d705 0x9bb93c 0x9bb9ac 0xb751d3 0x1e5aafe 0x1e5aa3d 0x1e387c2 0x1e37f44 

    0x1e37e1b 0x3c0f7e3 0x3c0f668 0x8adffc 0x287d 0x27a5)  libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

This is the didselect method and preparesegue for passing that array to another viewcontroller

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"bookItem"]) {

    NSDictionary *currentBook = [[_freeBooks objectForKey:@"freebook"] objectAtIndex:[[[self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems] objectAtIndex:0] row]];

    NSLog(@"%@", currentBook);

    GMMDetailpage *detailpage = (GMMDetailpage *)[segue destinationViewController];
    detailpage.bookDetails = currentBook;

    NSLog(@"%@",detailpage.bookDetails);
}

}
```

The value of current book is printing and its fine.... but after this it executes some other system codes and then it shows exception  .check image [image]

Comment: Didn't you understand with the error?

Comment: nop,i checked array's but its not empty

Comment: Please post some code, there is a array out of bounds exception means you are trying to access a array with no elements.

Comment: You are trying to access empty array by "objectAtIndex" method , so that only, you got error like this. Check your code , at any situation , your array may get not filled.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya  check my question,i updated and added my codes

Comment: @mani  check my question,i updated and added my codes

Comment: please print that array count before its getting crash

Comment: I printed the array element  its show 1 elements (the elemet i clicked)

Comment: In this statement `NSDictionary *currentBook = [[_freeBooks objectForKey:@"freebook"] objectAtIndex:[[[self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems] objectAtIndex:0] row]];` , it getting crashed.. check your `self.collectionView` array and also `freebook's selectedPath array`..

Comment: Iam getting th dictionary value"currentBook" that means it not crashing inside that function

Answer (score 0):

You are doing two array accesses, so the error comes from the fact that one of the two arrays is empty.

The two arrays are

```
[self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems]
```

and

```
[_freeBooks objectForKey:@"freebook"]
```

Check both the array independently and find out which one is the empty one.